# Split column containing email addresses

Tags: r

I want to split a column containing emailaddresses at the "@".

```
d$domain<-strsplit( d$email, "@")[[1]]
```

Does not work. What is the correct  way to do this?

Comment: Is @ a metacharacter for regular expressions?  If so, you may need to precede it by "\\". See http://127.0.0.1:15646/library/base/html/strsplit.html

Comment: Or you may need to index the `unlist` of `strsplit( d$email, "@")`, e.g. `d$domain<-unlist(strsplit( d$email, "@"))[1] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Maybe) more than one line is necessary:

```
for (i in 1:length(row.names(d)){    
d$domain[i]<-unlist(strsplit( d$email[i], "@"))[2]
}
```

(Note: `d$email` must be `character` and not `factor` and while you used 1 as the index in your question, the index of 2 will correspond to an email's domain)

Update: I think there is still a way to complete this task in one line by using 'apply' but I'm not sure how to do this ... yet.

One line answer (after defining function):
`fn <- function(x){unlist(strsplit(x,"@"))[2]}`
`d$domain <- lapply(d$email, fn)`

Comment: Thanks but your command fills each column with the domain part of the first row's email. Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for accepting my answer. I did figure out a one-line answer. See above (again).

Comment: Hmm. Better to use `strsplit` directly on the vector of emails, as Stedy does.  That answer can be put in one line easily: `sapply(strsplit(name,"@"), "[", 2)`.

Answer (score 10):

`str_split_fixed` from the `stringr` package makes this easy:

```
library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(d$email, "@", n = 2)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a regular expression -- they're fun!

```
d <- data.frame(email=rep(bob@bob.com, 10))
d$address <- gsub("@.*", "", d$email)
d$domain <- gsub(".*@", "", d$email)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the right idea, but you are just parsing it wrong.  Try this:

```
name <- "fakename@email.com"
splitname <- strsplit(name, "@")
emailid <- sapply(splitname, "[", 1)
domain <- sapply(splitname, "[", 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also make a matrix with a row for each half of the address, like this, and easily select whichever part you wanted.

```
matrix(unlist(strsplit(name,"@")),nrow=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that should take care of splitting the emails for you. It returns a list with the local and domain parts of the email.

```
parse.email <- function(emails) {
email.list <- strsplit(emails, split = '@')
# Preallocate the vectors
n <- length(email.list)
local <-  vector(length = n)
domain <-  vector(length = n)
for (i in 1:n){
    local[i] <- email.list[[i]][1]
    domain[i] <- email.list[[i]][2]
}
l <- list(local, domain)
names(l) <- c('local', 'domain')
return(l)}
```